# This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (38)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a switch case statement for my filters.
    But it throws me complexity issues of 39 can u help me solve it??

Below is my sample code.  It includes some more cases.

```
    angular.forEach(docsClone, function(doc) {
                var added = false;
                angular.forEach($scope.filterOptions, function(opt) {
                    if (!added) {
                        switch (opt.AttributeId) {
                            case 'documentStatus':
                                if ((doc.documentStatus !== undefined && doc.documentStatus !== null && doc.documentStatus.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1)) {
                                    filteredDocs.push(doc);
                                    added = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'planStatus':
                                if ((doc.planStatus !== undefined && doc.planStatus.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1)) {
                                    filteredDocs.push(doc);
                                    added = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'planFamily':
                                if ((doc.planProductFamily !== undefined && doc.planProductFamily !== null && doc.planProductFamily.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1)) {
                                    filteredDocs.push(doc);
                                    added = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'planYear':
                                planYear(doc, opt.AttributeValue, filteredDocs, added);
                                break;
                            case 'documentType':
                                if ((doc.documentType !== undefined && doc.documentType !== null && doc.documentType.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1)) {
                                    filteredDocs.push(doc);
                                    added = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'businessEntity':
                                if ((doc.businessEntity !== undefined && doc.businessEntity !== null && doc.businessEntity.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1)) {
                                    filteredDocs.push(doc);
                                    added = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'productClass':
                                if ((doc.productClass !== undefined && doc.productClass !== null && doc.productClass !== null && doc.productClass.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1) ||
                                    (doc.planProductClass !== undefined && doc.planProductClass.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1)) {
                                    filteredDocs.push(doc);
                                    added = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'productType':
                                if ((doc.productType !== undefined && doc.productType !== null && doc.productType.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1) ||
                                    (doc.planProductType !== undefined && doc.planProductType.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1)) {
                                    filteredDocs.push(doc);
                                    added = true;
                                }
                                break;
    }
```

Comment: Who/what "throws"? I'm pretty sure, Angular does not care about code complexity.

Comment: Start by extracting the code in each case to a function call, as you did for planYear. Notice that many cases do the exact same thing: only the attribute changes. So you could refactor that in a single function taking the attribute name as argument. `if (doc.documentType !== undefined && doc.documentType !== null)` could be reduced to `if (doc.documentType)`.

Comment: This might be more suitable for code review.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a lot of common conditions, why not break down into something common :

```
    angular.forEach(docsClone, function(doc) {
      var added = false;
      angular.forEach($scope.filterOptions, function(opt) {
          if (!added) {
              switch (opt.AttributeId) {
                  case 'planStatus':
                      planYear(doc, opt.AttributeValue, filteredDocs, added);
                      break;
                  case 'documentType':
                  case 'documentStatus':
                  case 'planStatus':
                  case 'planFamily':
                      if ((doc[opt.AttributeId] !== undefined && doc[opt.AttributeId] !== null && doc[opt.AttributeId].indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1)) {
                          filteredDocs.push(doc);
                          added = true;
                      }
                      break;
              }
          }
      });
    }
```

You can generalise your case statements depending upon the comparisons / manipulations performed.

Comment: the way you mentioned is correct but i ve two different filters one for documents and another one fore plans. when i put it as common it breaks evrythng and again i need to add more cases

Comment: .Example  case 'productClass':
                                if ((doc.productClass !== undefined && doc.productClass !== null && doc.productClass !== null && doc.productClass.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1) ||
                                    (doc.planProductClass !== undefined && doc.planProductClass.indexOf(opt.AttributeValue) !== -1)) {
                                    filteredDocs.push(doc);
                                    added = true;
                                }
                                break;